# How can I Add css to siple_form_for in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form-for

How to add CSS class to simple_form_for collection fields

```
<%= f.input :answer, as: :radio_buttons, :required => true, :label => false, collection: ([[image_tag(q.optiona),'a'] , [image_tag(q.optionb),'b'], [image_tag(q.optionc),'c'], [image_tag(q.optiond), 'd']]), wrapper: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes, :input_html => {:class => "img img-thumbnail", :width => 304, :height => 236} %>
```

The above code is displaying images in its actual size, I want show the images in thumbnails.

Comment: Could you post the HTML you get and the HTML you're after? Btw, plenty of classes are already added by simple_form itself... so maybe you don't need any new classes. Let us know if you're after the trick of adding a class to the collection container, or just the end-result :)

Comment: images are displaying but very large size(its actual size), i want to display very small size like 200X200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to preprocess images on the web, not simply scaling images down with css or image attributes. If you've just 4 images I'd open an editor like [gimp](https://www.gimp.org/) (a free and opensource Photoshop alternative). If you're working with user uploaded images use a gem like [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) which allows you to create special uploaders that, using a command line tool called [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), can automatically resize images down to reasonable sizes. However, a reason why you might want to use double sized, or even triple sized images is because of retina displays these days.

Back to your code. First simplify the code:

```
<%= f.input :answer, as: :radio_buttons, :required => true, collection: ([[image_tag(q.optiona),'a'] , [image_tag(q.optionb),'b'], [image_tag(q.optionc),'c'], [image_tag(q.optiond), 'd']]) %>
```

The following CSS code would then help you, even without a special wrapper:

```
.input.radio_buttons .radio img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Final remark: you don't provide any alt-text to your images, and while the `image_tag`-helper will add a generated alt tag for you based on the filename, it is recommended to add a nicely written one just in case someone cannot see the label-images (well). :)